# ServiceStack CryptUtils Issue

Tags: encryption, servicestack

I am trying to use ServiceStack's CryptUtils class to encrypt/decrypt data using "static" key value (the same key at different times/sessions).  The code I'm using is below.  The public and private keys were generated using CryptUtils.

The issue is that every time I run my test program, encryptedAddress is a different value (I was expecting the same value each time I ran the program).

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

```
    class Program {
    const string PUBLIC_KEY = "<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>5/tn3eY3KpQUvlJ3u...";
    const string PRIVATE_KEY = "<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>5/tn3eY3KpQUvlJ3u...";

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        RsaKeyPair keyPair = new RsaKeyPair();
        keyPair.PrivateKey = PRIVATE_KEY;
        keyPair.PublicKey = PUBLIC_KEY;

        string address = "1234 Any Street";
        string encryptedAddress = CryptUtils.Encrypt(keyPair.PublicKey, address, RsaKeyLengths.Bit2048);
        string decryptedAddress = CryptUtils.Decrypt(keyPair.PrivateKey, encryptedAddress, RsaKeyLengths.Bit2048);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's by design Encryption uses different random padding resulting in different encrypted values which reduces it being susceptible to plaintext attacks. It's only important that it gets decrypted with the private key back to its original value.